# What does standard deviation mean when using Predict[]?

Tags: machine-learning, precision-and-accuracy

I am using the Machine Learning function `Predict[data, Method -> "DecisionTree"]`, and I am trying to get the most accurate measurement of its accuracy. When I use `PredictorMeasurements[p, testdata, "StandardDeviation"]`, I get a standard deviation of 0.0457024, which for me seems to be good. However, I do not really understand what this measurement means. Is the standard deviation only a number that decreases as I increase the number of testdata points? Or is it telling me how accurate my Predict function gives the correct prediction?

If I want to know how accurate my `Predict[]` is, is there a function that would give me that besides actually comparing the predictions with correct data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I understand, it's literally just the `StandardDeviation` of the residuals (i.e., differences between prediction and actual value).

Comment: I don't think you can ever know how "accurate" a model is without testing it on data, but when making a prediction some ML methods allow you to compute the "uncertainty" of the prediction